# How to find the sum of the maximum product?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

When given n integers, you can multiply two numbers or leave them as they are. I wrote an algorithm to find the maximum value of all the values added together.

For example, the input is:

9(length of array)
-1 -8 2 1 3 6 -5 0 1

The output needs to be 62:

62=-8x-5+0x-1+6x3+2+1+1

If the array is `7 4 1 2 5 3 1 9 0`, the answer should be 91. If the array is `-13  7  -12  13  -8  4  12  7  15  6  -2  10  9  15  4  1  -15`, the answer should be 838.

I made my code like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "sop.h"
using namespace std;

sop::sop() {
    this->num = 0;
    this->array = NULL;
}

sop::sop(int* a, int n) {
    this->num = n;
    this->array = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) this->array[i] = a[i];
}

sop::~sop() {
    if (this->array) {
        delete[] this->array;
    }
    this->num = 0;
    this->array = NULL;
}

void sop::printArray(void) {
    if (!this->num)  return;
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) cout << array[i] << "  ";
    cout << endl;
}

int myMax(int a, int b) {
    return (a > b) ? a : b;
}

int sop::maxSOP() {
    if (num == 0) return 0;
    if (num == 1) return array[0];

    int maxSum = array[0]; // Initialize maxSum to the first element
    int currentMax = array[0]; // Initialize currentMax to the first element

    for (int i = 1; i < num; i++) {
        int temp = currentMax; // Store the previous currentMax

        // Calculate the current maximum product including the current element
        currentMax = myMax(array[i], myMax(currentMax * array[i], temp * array[i]));

        // Update maxSum with the maximum of maxSum and currentMax
        maxSum = myMax(maxSum, currentMax);
    }

    return maxSum;
}
```

`maxSOP` and `myMax` is what I did.

In this code, the result comes to 288, not 62. I don't know why. Could you fix this code, please? I will show you other files that can help you fix this code.

otherfile.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "sop.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int i = 0;
    int num = 0;
    int* array = NULL;
    ifstream fin;
    sop* _sop = NULL;

    if (argc > 1) {
        fin.open(argv[1]);
        if (!fin.is_open()) {
            cerr << "File " << argv[1] << " does not exist!" << endl;
            exit(0);
        }
        fin >> num;
        array = new int[num];
        for (i = 0;i < num;i++)        fin >> array[i];
        fin.close();
    }
    else {
        cin >> num;
        array = new int[num];
        for (i = 0;i < num;i++)        cin >> array[i];
    }

    _sop = new sop(array, num);
    cout << "Input array: ";
    _sop->printArray();
    cout << "Maximum sum of products = " << _sop->maxSOP() << endl;
    delete _sop;
    if (array)       delete[] array;
    array = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

otherheader.h

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "sop.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int i = 0;
    int num = 0;
    int* array = NULL;
    ifstream fin;
    sop* _sop = NULL;

    if (argc > 1) {
        fin.open(argv[1]);
        if (!fin.is_open()) {
            cerr << "File " << argv[1] << " does not exist!" << endl;
            exit(0);
        }
        fin >> num;
        array = new int[num];
        for (i = 0;i < num;i++)        fin >> array[i];
        fin.close();
    }
    else {
        cin >> num;
        array = new int[num];
        for (i = 0;i < num;i++)        cin >> array[i];
    }

    _sop = new sop(array, num);
    cout << "Input array: ";
    _sop->printArray();
    cout << "Maximum sum of products = " << _sop->maxSOP() << endl;
    delete _sop;
    if (array)       delete[] array;
    array = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ***in this code. result comes to 288 not 62 I don't know why.*** A quick and easy way to find out why your code is having some unexpected behavior is to use a simple example and step through it with a debugger line by line looking at the variables and flow after each individual line of code is executed until the code does something you did not expect.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you achieve the highest sum if you are able to pair numbers together efficiently. I suggest the following rules:

1. Numbers <= 0 should be paired together.
   For `n1 <= 0` and `n2 <= 0`, `n1 * n2 >= n1 + n2`.
   Contrary to `n1 <= 0` paired with `n2 > 0`: `n1 * n2 < n1 + n2` which is **not** the pairing we want.
2. `1`'s should never be paired.
   Same as above: if we were to pair `n` with 1, the resulting product would always be less than `n+1`.
3. Numbers > 1 should be paired together.
   No matter what `n1 > 1` and `n2 > 1` you pick, `n1 * n2 >= n1 + n2` (both sides are equal only if `n1 = n2 = 2`; in every other case, this is a strict inequality).
4. When you have more than 2 numbers you can pair (as explained in the above 3 rules), always go for higher absolute values first.
   Example for 3 integers `1 < n1 <= n2 <= n3`:
   `n2 * n3 + n1 >= n1 * n3 + n2 >= n1 * n1 + n3 >= n1 + n2 + n3`.
   Something similar goes for 4 integers `1 < n1 <= n2 <= n3 <= n4`: the biggest combination you can build is `n1 * n2 + n3 * n4`.

---

That pretty much puts us on track; we have to:

1. Sort the numbers (because of rule 4)
2. Treat the list in 3 segments (because of rules 1, 2, 3). At every step, we process items in pairs first (i.e. increasing iterators by 2), then if the segment had an odd number of elements, we add the smallest (in absolute value) remaining item to the sum.
   The algorithm looks slightly asymmetrical because, as `1`'s are expected to be in the middle of the vector, we will handle them right following the loop on negative numbers (rather than restarting from `numbers.begin()`).

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //std::vector<int> numbers{ -1, -8, 2, 1, 3, 6, -5, 0, 1 };
    //std::vector<int> numbers{ 7, 4, 1, 2, 5, 3, 1, 9, 0 };
    std::vector<int> numbers{ -13,  7, -12,  13, -8,  4,  12,  7,  15,  6, -2,  10,  9,  15,  4,  1, -15 };

    int sum = 0;
    std::sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());
    {
        //Start with numbers <= 0 
        auto iter1 = numbers.begin(), iter2 = iter1 + 1;
        for (; iter2 != numbers.end() && *iter2 <= 0; iter2 += 2) {
            sum += *iter1 * *iter2;
            iter1 += 2;
            if (iter1 == numbers.end())
                break;
        }
        //Process the 1's
        for (;iter1 != numbers.end() && *iter1 <= 1; ++iter1)
            sum += *iter1;
    }
    {
        //Process numbers > 0 (using a reverse iterator)
        auto iter1 = numbers.rbegin(), iter2 = iter1 + 1;
        for (; iter2 != numbers.rend() && *iter2 > 1; iter2 += 2) {
            sum += *iter1 * *iter2;
            iter1 += 2;
            if (iter1 == numbers.rend())
                break;
        }
        if (iter1 != numbers.rend() && *iter1 > 1)
            sum += *iter1;
    }
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I let you add back all the lines to push user input into `numbers`.

In case you wonder, complexity is `O(n log(n))` because of the initial sorting.

Comment: This demonstrates the principle well, but needs a bit of work to finish it off, since `iter2 += 2` can be UB when we have numbers that are all positive or all negative.  And OP should add a good suite of tests to flush out the remaining bugs.

Comment: That is a good point, took me longer than I expected to write my answer and I guess I rushed the details just a bit too much. It is now corrected + added small details while I was at it.